# Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable on third party API url

Tags: magento2, api

I am using third party API URL from `NAV` and it has predefined variable to be passsed in the API.

URL is something like this
`MAINAPIHOSTURL/PostedSalesHeaderAPI?$filter=No%20eq%20%27FZPSI-00010%27&$format=json`

Here `$filter` and `$format` is predefine variable used in API section.
when use like this in magento code it show error like
`Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: filter`

When i define it using below code like
 `$filter = ''; $format = '';` in the function it passed empty in url so i am not able to get result from api call.

What can we do for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it was an ugly mistake from my side it definitely helps someone when his mind stops on this.

Here I have defined it like this.

```
<?php $url = "MAINAPIHOSTURL/PostedSalesHeaderAPI?$filter=No%20eq%20%27FZPSI-00010%27&$format=json" ?>
```

Here in URL `$format` and `$filter` will be parsed in PHP compiler as variable because we have used `"` to bind string but it gives notice when strict mode is enabled because it is not defined anywhere.
so the solution is simple yet easy

we can pass it as follow so the PHP compiler considers it as a string not a variable.

```
<?php $url = "MAINAPIHOSTURL/PostedSalesHeaderAPI?".'$filter=No%20eq%20%27FZPSI-00010%27&$format=json';?>
```

Here we have to use `'` to bind string so it will consider as a string.